# topology of complex projective varieties.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

[image]

In this

I have the problem in understanding the underlined lines?
 Also i don't understand how $\rho (y)$ not being transversal relate to maximal rank of $\rho$? What does rank mean here? Is it the same as we define in differential topology?
Any help is appreciated.